# Why microcontrollers contain external memory controllers?

Tags: microcontroller

I´m doing a quiz for school and I can´t find the answer to this question anywhere. The question is:

> Microcontrollers contain external memory controllers because________:
>   - communication controllers and other peripherals require external memory to operate
>   - some microcontrollers do not contain any internal memory
>  
>   - all microcontrollers require an external ROM to boot up
>   - all of the above

I know this is a silly question but I don´t know what else to do.

Comment: All of the above.  Minor note: This question is more suited to Electrical Engineering StackExchange: http://electronics.stackexchange.com.  We answer programming and software questions here only.

Comment: thank you !!! can you explain why a bit so I can understand ?

Comment: There's really no need to explain.  You can think of at least one microcontroller in the industry where external memory controllers are used for each case.

Comment: Related question and answer: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/134496/why-do-microcontrollers-have-so-little-ram

Comment: Just to be contrary, I think it's "none of the above", strictly speaking, since there are counter-examples for each of the given answers. ;-)

Comment: @PaulR - Yes! That makes sense.  Maybe the OP should put "None of the Above" as an additional choice :D

Comment: Well I submitted my test and it says that the answer all of the above is wrong, but it dose't tell me the correct answer... thank you either way

Comment: @Dany - Oops.  Sorry to hear that!  BTW, you should probably delete your question because (1) it isn't useful for this community and (2) it's nothing related to programming.